# SwiftUI Xcode 11 beta 5 / 6: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Since beta 5 my Project won't compile anymore. The error is `"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"`for that Button's Text.
I thought it would be  fixed with beta 6 maybe, but it wasn't. macOS is also updated to Catalina beta 7.

```
 class ClPassport : ObservableObject , Identifiable {


    @Published var mrz : String =  "" //{ didSet { update() } } 
    var isValid : Bool {
        return true
    }

    func update() {
        objectWillChange.send(())
    }

    func getMRZKey() -> String {
     return ""
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {

    @ObservedObject var passportDetails = ClPassport()
      var body: some View {

         ZStack{
           VStack(alignment: .leading){
             HStack{
                  Spacer()
                  Button(action: {
                      self.scanPassport( mrzKey: self.passportDetails.getMRZKey() )
                    }) {
                        Text("Read Chip") // <-  "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(passportDetails.isValid ? .primary : Color.secondary.opacity(0.25))
                            .padding()
                        }.padding()
                        .background(Color.white.opacity(passportDetails.isValid ? 1 : 0.5))
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                        .padding()
                        .disabled( !passportDetails.isValid )
                   Spacer()
              }
            TextField($passportDetails.mrz, placeholder: Text("MRZ"))
            }
          }
        }

 func scanPassport( mrzKey: String ) {
   //do stuff with mrzKey
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance that this is inside a `ForEach` which takes Binding<T> as the closure-iterating type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update in your answer, I see some changes needed:

- Use `ObservableObject` (no need to use `Combine.ObservableObject`)
- Missing function `scanPassport`, I added a bogus one.
- `willChange` no longer exists, it is now `objectWillChange`. And it is autosynthesize for you.

```swift
import SwiftUI

class ClPassport : ObservableObject , Identifiable {


    @Published var mrz : String =  "" //{ didSet { update() } }
    var isValid : Bool {
        return true
    }

    func update() {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }

    func getMRZKey() -> String {
     return ""
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {

    @ObservedObject var passportDetails = ClPassport()
      var body: some View {

         ZStack{
           VStack(alignment: .leading){
             HStack{
                  Spacer()
                  Button(action: {
                      self.scanPassport( mrzKey: self.passportDetails.getMRZKey() )
                    }) {
                        Text("Read Chip")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(passportDetails.isValid ? .primary : Color.secondary.opacity(0.25))
                            .padding()
                        }.padding()
                        .background(Color.white.opacity(passportDetails.isValid ? 1 : 0.5))
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                        .padding()
                        .disabled( !passportDetails.isValid )
                   Spacer()
              }
            TextField("MRZ", text: $passportDetails.mrz)
            }
          }
        }

 func scanPassport( mrzKey: String ) {
   //do stuff with mrzKey
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that, I added the some code for the class of passport details. Maybe there's something wrong?

Comment: Also note that you can use @Published to avoid having to call objectWillChange.send()

Comment: Thanks for the fixes! Unfortunately it still produces the same error. I added another string property `mrz` of which I have a couple of the same kind (`didSet ...`). Maybe there's an error?

Comment: Well.... the code as I posted it, compiles fine. If you update the answer, I'll be happy to have another look. Also note send() should be called from willSet , not didSet. Although you can avoid it all together, if you declare your property @Published.

Comment: I updated my post with your suggestions. Also, I made the mrz property @Published.

Comment: Your code, exactly as you posted it now, compiles with no error  I’m using beta 6. Maybe your problem is somewhere else completely. Try commenting your entire ZStack and put Text(””) in its place. Maybe the error will manifest properly.

Comment: I commented everything until it compiled successfully. The Button is not commented and compiles as well. I uncommented each element until a build error occurred. Seems as if the `TextField` causes the error.

Comment: Done. You need to change your textfield to `TexfField("placaholder", text: binding)`. I updated the code in the answer.

Comment: Awesome... thank you! One addition: If add `.textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)` to the TextField I get the same error again. has this been deprecated as well?

Comment: yeap, you need to use `.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Do you think that Xcode will be more helpful in finding those issues after it has left beta status?

Comment: I wouldn't count on it Maybe next year. For the time being, the best debugging tool is commenting out progressively, until the error shifts somewhere else. :-(