# SwiftUI: Why does ForEach($strings) (text: Binding<String>) not build?

Tags: swiftui

I have a `ForEach` which takes a Binding<[String]> and it compiled with Xcode11 beta5 fine but with beta6 it says `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` on the `Text("...")` inside the `ForEach` and I can't find the mistake. Is it that I can't iterate over such a binding anymore?

```
struct ForEachItem1: View {
    @Binding var items: [String]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($items) { item in
            Text("Hello world") // Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
        }
    }
}

struct ForEachItem2: View {
    @Binding var items: [String]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($items) { (item: Binding<String>) in
            Text("Hello world") // Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be item.wrappedValue.dietName

Comment: @MichaelSalmon it does not make a difference - still the same error on the same line sadly, but you had the right idea. I simplified it. Thanks for looking at it. This is bugging me all morning. I have the feeling this is sth similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568662/swiftui-xcode-11-beta-5-6-type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-contex

Comment: Xcode doesn't always report where the problem lies ;^(

Comment: @MichaelSalmon True :) I however finally found out. Beta6 removed Binding conformance to Collection :D

Answer (score 1):

The conditional conformance of `Binding` to `Collection` was removed (see Xcode11 Beta5 Release Notes for deprecation notice). It can't be found in later release notes/releases.